# Typescript Error assigning VITE_API_URL to axios' baseURL

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vite

I have a very basic axios setup on a Vue 3 application built on Vite & Typescript.  However, I'm receiving a typescript error for "baseURL" that reads:

> Type 'string | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
> Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2322)

As clearly implied `VITE_API_URL` is of type `string | boolean | undefined`, but `baseURL` doesn't like accepting booleans. Now, obviously I'm not attempting to assign a boolean to this property, but its typing indicates it *could be*, which is enough to upset it.

Now Vite has an interface defined for `VITE_API_URL` as follows:

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  [key: string]: string | boolean | undefined
  BASE_URL: string
  MODE: string
  DEV: boolean
  PROD: boolean
  SSR: boolean
}
```

If I were the one who created this interface, I'd just remove the boolean, as I'll never be setting a boolean for this value, but I'm not satisfied that changing Vite's built-in interface is the right course of action here.

I'm still expanding my Typescript knowledge, so I'm hoping this is something simple that I'm missing, but I cannot seem to find any solutions to getting these two to play nice.  Considering how prevalent both Vite and Axios are, I'm hoping someone else has run into this and found a simple solution.  Any help would be appreciated!

`httpClient.ts` below:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default httpClient;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [augment `ImportMetaEnv`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#intellisense-for-typescript) to add the type for any custom environment variables you're using:

1. In `src/env.d.ts` (create if needed), add the following code:

   ```js
   /// <reference types="vite/client" />

   interface ImportMetaEnv {
     readonly VITE_API_URL: string
   }
   ```
2. If using VS Code, you might need to restart the TypeScript server (or the IDE itself) for the types to be reloaded.

[image: screenshot]